# SQL Left Join not returning first match

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables where I would like to return all data in the left table and the matching data in the right.

The problem is, that the data returned on the left does not include the rows that matches the right.

Left table:

### b_kategori

```
id, kat, navn
32, 1, 'Bits'
33, 2, 'Donkrafte'
34, 3,'Dornsæt'
35, 4, 'Hammere'
```

### b_underkategori

```
id, kat, navn
26, 1, 'Skrueudtrækkertoppe'
27, 1, 'WIHA Bits'
```

The SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT k.kat, k.navn as navnet, u.navn as unavn FROM b_kategori k LEFT OUTER JOIN b_underkategori u ON k.kat = u.kat
```

I would expect the SQL to return all rows on the left (b_kategori) and also all rows on the right (b_underkategori), but I am missing the b_kategori `32, 1, 'Bits'` Is this excluded because it matches the right table data, or is it possible to get the SQL to return all data?

The above SQL is stripped down to a minimum so I can debug it. The "original" also has a WHERE statement. If I can get the above to work I believe I also can get the original to work. :-)

I hope someone can guide me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot replicate this behaviour

Comment: its possible that your where clause is in effect voided your join

Comment: That select does show all the rows from b_kategori. Which will be easier to see if you also select k.id. In fact, it'll shows k.id=32 twice because of the left join. I agree with @happymacarts, probably something to do with the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Left join intersection](http://www.dofactory.com/sql/left-outer-join), if your left table dont have a match on the right table, it will cut that part, replace it with [FULL JOIN](http://www.dofactory.com/sql/full-outer-join) and that i think will get what you want.